# Cancellation of contractibility of fibres

Tags: gn.general-topology

Suppose given maps $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ such that $f$ and $g \circ f$ both have contractible fibres.  Then does $g$ have contractible fibres?

And, the same question, but with the maps assumed to be morphisms of algebraic varieties and contractible replaced with isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ (for varying $n$).

Answer (score 5):

Without an additional assumption about properness or a fibration-like property, there are pretty simple counterexamples:
$X=[0,1)$, $Y=S^1$, $Z=\ast$, $f(x)=e^{2 \pi  i x}$.

Answer (score 2):

If your spaces are path-connected, locally compact separable metric spaces (with some additional local connectedness assumptions), and the maps are all proper (inverse images of compact sets are compact) and *onto*, then the [Vietoris mapping theorem](http://www.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/Smale_1957b.pdf) can be applied.

You can conclude that the map $g$ is weak homotopy equivalence. If $g$ is a fibration, this implies that its fibres are all weakly contractible. If $Y$ and $Z$ are CW-complexes, then the fibres of $g$ are of the homotopy type of a CW complex (by a theorem of Milnor) and hence are contractible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that "fibres" means "inverse images of points".  I hope I'm not misinterpreting.

If $X$ is a point, then all of the fibres of $f$ and $g\circ f$ are either singletons or empty, hence contractible.  But the map $g$ can be anything at all.

Comment: The empty space is not contractible - it is not homotopy equivalent to a point. In particular, this implies that both $f$ and $g\circ f$  are surjective, so the fibres of $g$ are non-empty. This is a loong way from knowing they are contractible though.